# Did young people REALLY drink alcohol in the 1800s?

Tags: culture, history, industrial-age, alcoholic-beverages

In my studying of the setting for my story, a fantasy world analogous to 1800 - 1850, I've found a number of interesting things - one of these is that people in the past did a lot of really odd things. Considering the number of these odd things, I want to include them as little details to make my story truly feel like it's in a different time. Saying there are guns and steam engines is not sufficient for me.

One of these things in the past was just the consumption of alcohol in early America (which is influencing a lot of my setting). I've read stuff claiming that many Americans, including children, would drink copious amounts of whiskey, due to poor drinking water.

Was such alcohol less concentrated? Also, am I correct in my assumption that in a warmer coastal region, rum would be the preferred drink?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129933/discussion-on-question-by-current-did-young-people-really-drink-alcohol-in-the-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everyone* (from what we'd now call kindergarten age or lower) drank "small beer" or watered wine on a routine basis for most of the second millennium.

First: "small beer" is made from the "second run" of sparging the sugars out of malt that's already been used for full strength beer; it's the medieval/renaissance version of "light beer" in that regard.  It has significantly less alcohol than the first run beer, lighter body and flavor, because it start with a much lower concentration of sugars and correspondingly less preservative/flavoring agents (hops since the 14th century or so, gruit or other fruit and herb mixtures before then).  After the second sparging, the spent or "spelt" grain would be dried, ground into flour, and used to make bread, so nothing wasted.

Second: small beer was safer for drinking (in most cases) than the water available in larger towns and cities (not the case for wells in the countryside, but anything larger than a village likely had contaminated water supply).  This was not because it contained alcohol, but because it was boiled before being put up to ferment, and because contaminated beer would reveal itself with strong unpleasant odors and tastes, much more noticeable than in water that even when safe likely contained high mineral content and often had soaked in wood barrels or run over plant matter before being collected.

Third: beer (especially unfiltered, unpasteurized beer such as home brewing would create) carried nutrition in the form of B vitamins and minerals that might otherwise be missing in a child's diet not informed by nutritional science.

Fourth: there was no inkling before the last half of the 19th century or even the early 20th that a small amount of alcohol was a bad choice for children; even the temperance movement was mainly concerned with the effects of habitual drunkenness, not that of a cup of small beer with breakfast.  Don't forget that it was also routine to give children medicines that contained morphine (or other opiates) or cocaine until the 1920s.

So, yes.  It was very common for children to consume alcohol (usually beer in the Germanic and Nordic derived parts of America and northern Europe, wine in the French and Italian derived part and in southern Europe), from about the time they were weaned, until the latter half of the 19th century at least (much later in many beer-drinking cultures; I knew an American of German descent who'd had beer as a child in the 1950s).

Comment: Isn't "everyone drank small beer" considered a myth by serious historians (e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/34535e/if_people_drank_beer_all_day_in_the_middle_ages/ )?

Comment: From your link: "firstly, they didn't drink 'all day' and secondly the beer was very dilute and weak" -- which is the "small beer" I cited.  First-run beer would get you drunk about like modern craft brew; small beer was in almost every way comparable to modern light beer -- lower alcohol, lower calorie content, lower body and flavor.  I doubt I could (when I drank regularly, before age and diabetes) get drunk without painful stomach distention on small beer; it commonly ran below 2% ABV, sometimes as low as the 1/2% of "near beer" (which is made much the same way).

Comment: *"I doubt I could // get drunk without painful stomach distention on small beer"* Accept the first year perhaps but not after that once you'd acclimatised to regular drinking, used to get drunk real easy when I was first able to go into a pub.

Comment: I was thinking more of "*The myth of constant beer drinking is also false; water was available to drink in many forms (rivers, rain water, melted snow) and was often used to dilute wine.*" and "*This is a myth about the medieval period: there was plenty of clean water. Outside of some sieges, there are no persistent, nor widespread, nor chronic references to shortages of clean water anywhere in medieval European sources that could suggest potable water was an issue.*" which directly contradicts "*Everyone ... drank "small beer*" from your answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know about Germany, but in many places it is still very common to give a little wine to children of primary school age, and a little more wine to children of high-school age, going to adult levels (in proportion to body weight) around 16. I don't understand how Americans can expect people to learn to drink responsibly if they have no experience until 25 or whatever is the "drinking age".

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan: Probably, "everyone" means most people in Germanic cities. In wine countries people drank wine, usually mixed with water; the habit of drinking beer expanded southwards only in the late 19th century. And yes you are right, before the large scale industrialization of the late 19th century most people lived in rural conditions, where water was perfectly safe to drink.

Comment: The other aspect about local water is that when people do not travel much, their systems are accustomed to the local bacteria in the water. Clean water is an issue for travelers, merchants, invading armies, etc. any people who move between water supply to water supply. I know one large US company CEO who went back to his home village in India after many years and thought he could drink the water there. He was sick for two weeks. His system was no longer used to those bacteria.

Comment: @DavidR Yes.  Montezuma's Revenge, they used to call it when tourists went to Acapulco or Guadalajara.  Stick with beer or wine, you never have that problem (at least as long as the kitchen is clean).